# The method I Want To Use Is Crossed Out

Tags: javascript, html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/795oL.png)

The method I want to use does its job, I get the URL from the console. I'm just wondering why the top is scratched. I could never understand the reason.

I wonder why this method is underlined while other methods are normal. In addition, although it is crossed out, the method does its job and does not give any errors. Why is it crossed out even though it doesn't give an error, what's the reason?

Answer (score 3):

Because it was deprecated.

> Deprecated: This feature is no longer recommended. Though some
> browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from
> the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or
> may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it, and
> update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the
> bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature
> may cease to work at any time.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain